# Edit svg dynamically in Android Compose

Tags: android, svg, android-jetpack-compose

I load a svg from assets with success with Coil in Compose.
But I need to edit this svg by adding new svg path in it. However I did not find anything to achieve that.
I tried [AndroidSvg](http://bigbadaboom.github.io/androidsvg/), but it generated canvas from Android API which is not the same as Compose Canvas, and I don't know how to use in Image as painter.

I search a lot on internet, but didn't find well about the manipulation of svg in android. Even if svg is not the most suitable for mobile, I'm suprised to find so few information. Do you have any suggestions, helps, examples...?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i see from documents it generates Bitmap from svg and that SVG is drawn to Canvas by passing Bitmap to Canvas constructor.

You can use `androidx.compose.foundation.Canvas` which is counterpart of Canvas in the library.

val canvas: androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Canvas = Canvas(imageBitmap)

Replacing these lines likely to solve the issue

```
val bmcanvas = androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Canvas(newBM.asImageBitmap())

// Render our document onto our canvas
svg.renderToCanvas(bmcanvas.nativeCanvas)
```

Comment: Looks like a good library.  I might use it in the future as well. Bookmarked this question for future references